# List linux directory structure and md5 of files in directories

Tags: linux, command

I'm trying to list the directory structure of a Linux server with the md5's of the files in each directory.

So far I have this:
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^/]*//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'

which lists it exactly how I want it, but I would also like md5 file outputs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`find -type f -exec md5sum "{}" + > checklist.chk`

I added an output file for clarity